# Google maps thinks im in different city

Tags: laptop

when I bring up google maps on my laptop, OS windows 11, it thinks I'm in another city
I tried clearing cookies, I don't know what to do

Comment: Does your laptop have a GPS? If not it will be using an IP lookup to guess your location which more often will correspond to where your ISP is headquartered.

Comment: Already answered on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57909/how-do-i-set-a-default-google-maps-location